# List of US under Epic with label

Tags: jira, jql

I need to build a query that finds me all US under epics where labels is not empty.

`project = xxx AND issuetype = "User Story" AND "Epic Link" IS NOT EMPTY AND "Epic Link" IN (epicOf("labels IS NOT EMPTY"))`

It doesn't work, i get an error "Cannot find functionJQL "epicOf(labels IS NOT EMPTY)".

Can anyone help?

Comment: To use "epicOf" JQL function, you should have ScriptRunner installed.